# .NET collection to support LIFO

Tags: .net, collections

I need a .NET that supports last in first out (LIFO).

Is there one?  If there are more than one what is the best?  (I plan to put `Form` objects in it.)

Any suggestions?

(NOTE: The collection needs to be on the Compact Framework. I am using Visual Studio 2008 and C#).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's the [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw%28VS.80%29.aspx) class, which is pretty much the purest LIFO you could ask for.

It is supported in the Compact Framework 2.0.